# How to use tmpfs in MariaDB when SELinux is enforced?

Tags: selinux, mariadb, alma-linux

Running AlmaLinux 9.2 and MariaDB 10.11.

Trying to use in my.cnf:

```
tmpdir = /dev/shm
```

This works fine when PHP-FPM is connecting using TCP port.

Now trying to use faster Socket (/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock) from PHP-FPM.

This doesn't work out of the box, but had to apply a workaround mentioned in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-30520:

```
chcon -t mysqld_exec_t /usr/sbin/mariadbd
```

After that MariaDB won't start, because it cannot access /dev/shm.

Then allowed access to tmpfs file context using mysqld_tmpfs.te policy per https://mariadb.com/kb/en/selinux/#allowing-access-to-the-tmpfs-file-context:

```
module mysqld_tmpfs 1.0;

require {
    type tmpfs_t;
    type mysqld_t;
    class dir { write search read remove_name open getattr add_name };
    class file { write getattr read lock create unlink open };
}

allow mysqld_t tmpfs_t:dir { write search read remove_name open getattr add_name };

allow mysqld_t tmpfs_t:file { write getattr read lock create unlink open };
```

MariaDB now runs, but when it tries to create temp files seeing the following errors using `ausearch -c 'mariadbd' --raw`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1690215382.357:58492): avc:  denied  { map } for  pid=602807 comm="mariadbd" path="/dev/shm/#sql-temptable-932b7-22f-62.MAD" dev="tmpfs" ino=1183 scontext=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:tmpfs_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1690215382.357:58492): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=no exit=-13 a0=0 a1=7 a2=3 a3=4001 items=0 ppid=1 pid=602807 auid=4294967295 uid=986 gid=985 euid=986 suid=986 fsuid=986 egid=985 sgid=985 fsgid=985 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="mariadbd" exe="/usr/sbin/mariadbd" subj=system_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 key=(null)ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=mmap AUID="unset" UID="mysql" GID="mysql" EUID="mysql" SUID="mysql" FSUID="mysql" EGID="mysql" SGID="mysql" FSGID="mysql"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1690215382.357:58492): proctitle="/usr/sbin/mariadbd"
```

or in human readable form:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/mariadbd from map access on the file /dev/shm/#sql-temptable-932b7-22f-62.MAD.

*****  Plugin restorecon_source (92.2 confidence) suggests   *****************

If you want to fix the label. 
/usr/sbin/mariadbd default label should be bin_t.
Then you can run restorecon.
Do
# /sbin/restorecon -v /usr/sbin/mariadbd

*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.83 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow domain to can mmap files
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'domain_can_mmap_files' boolean.

Do
setsebool -P domain_can_mmap_files 1

*****  Plugin catchall (1.41 confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that mariadbd should be allowed map access on the #sql-temptable-932b7-22f-62.MAD file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'mariadbd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mariadbd
# semodule -X 300 -i my-mariadbd.pp
```

Please advise.

Comment: Putting `tmpdir` into `/dev/shm` seems very wrong. Why do you do that?

Comment: Seeing "Temporary tables created on disk: 40% (108K on disk / 268K total)" even though tmp_table_size = 384M and max_heap_table_size = 384M is in place. It's a large WordPress database, so trying to find the cause there also. In the meantime would like to store temp files in memory instead on disk.

Comment: why? Is there benchmarks that suggest that approach? Things that mariadb/InnoDB can do in RAM, it does on RAM. All you gain by putting temporary tablespace into RAM is that you make your Linux flush out page cache earlier due to memory pressure from tmpfs when you need it the most.

Comment: After switching to socket instead of TCP port and commenting out `tmpdir = /dev/shm` editors started complaining things are slower.

Comment: as said: I doubt putting `tmpdir` on a `tmpfs` is even remotely a good idea. Could you explain to me why you come to the conclusion that it is?

Comment: You can Google for: `tmpdir tmpfs mysql`

Found the sort-of-benchmark you've been asking about: https://2bits.com/articles/reduce-your-servers-resource-usage-moving-mysql-temporary-directory-ram-disk.html

Also official MariaDB page says:
`If you wanted to mount your tmpdir on a tmpfs file system or wanted to use a tmpfs file system on /run/shm, then you might need to allow mysqld_t to have access to a couple tmpfs-related file contexts`: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/selinux/#allowing-access-to-the-tmpfs-file-context

Comment: that is more than ten years old; a lot have happened in Linux scheduling and storage subsystems; I don't intend to say "just because it's old it doesn't apply anymore", though it is my intuition that with the improved storage devices of the last decade and aforementioned incremental improvements in the linux kernel, that'd be true. Are you really suffering from many *slow* queries? And: have you tried increasing page cache sizes and dirty cache ages&amount by the same amount that your tmpfile directory is now eating RAM?

Comment: mariadb documentation has the same problem (not nearly as badly, though) as PHP official documentation has: the one-eyed writing documentation for the blind; not everything that the MariaDB wiki says works is a *good idea*.

Comment: So,  the question whether you're really gaining anything would have to be answered by you, the same way that 2bits article did it: Do a benchmark and a profiling before. Is *slow queries* the problem you're dealing with? MariaDB has a special log only for these! Does the number actually change with the change of tmpdir? What I don't understand about the 2bits.com article is that what they claim was a *bad* statistics before seems to be very terribly for tmpfs: The amount of blocks *written* is multiple times larger than *read*. In that case, using tmpfs will quickly bring you into swapping,

Comment: because mariadb effectively uses that tmpdir as *cold* storage. Something that wouldn't be any slower when stored on a disk, but with low pressure to actually write dirty pages to disk! Tmpfs uses the very same RAM as your Linux kernel uses for buffering writes; it's *not* inherently faster, at all. Sure (unless you're swapping, when everything goes to shit, anyways), when eventually reading back some of the data, mariaDB would have to wait for that storage – but for the majority of data, which, according to 2bit's own benchmark, never gets read back – tmpfs would *still* be occupying RAM, and

Comment: that same RAM wouldn't be available for disk cache, neither for the tmpdir nor for the actual data storage paths. That's a solution with more down- than upsides!

Comment: `SLOW QUERIES
The slow query log is enabled.
Current long_query_time = 2.000000 sec.
Since startup, 59 out of 3226927 queries have taken longer than <long_query_time-when-they-were-executed> to complete.
Your long_query_time seems reasonable.`

Comment: That was output from https://github.com/BMDan/tuning-primer.sh

I do understand your point. Should I change `long_query_time` from 2 to 1 second, change PHP-FPM back to using TCP port and then log all slow queries with `tmpdir = /dev/shm` enabled. Then comment this line out and log another round? Or you had some different kind of benchmark/profiling in mind?

Comment: It really doesn't seem you know the problem that you're solving yet! Investigate further. I wouldn't see what the advantage of reducing the `long_query_time` would be, as that's just relevant for how many queries you log as slow – and these are so few that it's unlikely you'll suddenly start seeing a problem.